# Flutter How Can I Get Markers from JSON API and show on Google Map

Tags: json, flutter, google-maps

I make a simple app get data marker from JSON API and draw them on Google Map.

I have get marker information from the API (URL) and added it to the list allMarkers.

But when I run my app, Map is not working and got this error:

`type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'`

**This is my full Home.dart code**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Home2State createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Future _future;

  Future loadString() async {
    var url = "http://10.0.2.2/GoApp/locations.php";
    var response = await http.get(url);
    final dynamic responsebody = jsonDecode(response.body);
    print(responsebody);
    return responsebody;
  }

  List<Marker> allMarkers = [];
  GoogleMapController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _future = loadString();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(children: [
        Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
              List<dynamic> parsedJson = jsonDecode(snapshot.data);

              allMarkers = parsedJson.map((i) {
                return Marker(
                  markerId: MarkerId(i['loc_id']),
                  position: LatLng(i['loc_x'], i['loc_y']),
                  onTap: () {},
                );
              }).toList();

              return GoogleMap(
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                    target: LatLng(40.7128, -74.0060), zoom: 1.0),
                markers: Set.from(allMarkers),
                onMapCreated: mapCreated,
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                tiltGesturesEnabled: true,
                compassEnabled: true,
                rotateGesturesEnabled: true,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }

  void mapCreated(controller) {
    setState(() {
      _controller = controller;
    });
  }
}
```

**My json data from URL:**

```
[
 { 
   "loc_id": "8D5D-4CD323560F59", 
   "loc_x": 40.7128, 
   "loc_y": -74.0060 
 },
 { 
   "loc_id": "E3E0D2C5-CB82", 
   "loc_x": 41.7128, 
   "loc_y": -75.0060 
 }
]
```

**How Can Resolved This Issuse?**

Comment: Hello welcome to StackOverflow, could you upload the json response that you receive from the api call that you are making

Comment: @yusufpats I have uploaded the json response that I receive from api.